# NSTimeInterval to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimeinterval

How can I convert a `NSTimeInterval` to `NSDate`? Think of it like a stopwatch. I want the initial date to be 00:00:00, and I have a `NSTimeInterval` of X seconds.

I need to do it like this because the `NSTimeInterval` needs to be converted to an int by using `lround` to round up, then converted to a `NSDate` to use the `NSDateFormatter` to throw it into a string.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

An `NSTimeInterval`, as its name, um, implies, doesn't represent the same thing as an `NSDate`. An `NSDate` is a *moment* in time. A time interval is a stretch of time. To get a point from an interval, you have to have another point. Your question is like asking "How do I convert 12 inches to a spot on this board I'm cutting?" Well, 12 inches, starting *from where*?

You need to pick a reference date. This will most likely be the `NSDate` representing the time that you started your counter. Then you can use [`+[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-SW14) or [`-[NSDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-SW13)

That said, I'm pretty sure you're thinking about this backwards. You're trying to display time elapsed since some starting point, i.e., the *interval*, not the current time. Every time you update the display, you should just be using the new interval. For example (assuming you have a timer firing periodically to do the update):

```
- (void) updateElapsedTimeDisplay: (NSTimer *)tim {

    // You could also have stored the start time using
    // CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    // Divide the interval by 3600 and keep the quotient and remainder
    div_t h = div(elapsedTime, 3600);
    int hours = h.quot;
    // Divide the remainder by 60; the quotient is minutes, the remainder
    // is seconds.
    div_t m = div(h.rem, 60);
    int minutes = m.quot;
    int seconds = m.rem;

    // If you want to get the individual digits of the units, use div again
    // with a divisor of 10.

    NSLog(@"%d:%d:%d", hours, minutes, seconds);
 }
```

Answer (score 15):

An easy conversion from and back is shown here:

```
 NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
 NSTimeInterval  tiNow = [now timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]; 
 NSDate * newNow = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:tiNow];
```

Ole K Hornnes

Answer (score 12):

I would advise against using `NSDateFormatter` if you wish to display time intervals. `NSDateFormatter` is useful when you wish to display times in the local, or a specific, timezone. But in this case it would be a bug if the time was timezone adjusted (e.g. one day per year has 23 hours).

```
NSTimeInterval time = ...;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02li:%02li:%02li",
                                              lround(floor(time / 3600.)) % 100,
                                              lround(floor(time / 60.)) % 60,
                                              lround(floor(time)) % 60];
```

Comment: perfect! just what I needed!

Answer (score 6):

If you have your initial date stored in an `NSDate` object, you can get a new date any interval in the future. Simply use `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` like this:

```
NSDate * originalDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval interval = 1;
NSDate * futureDate = [originalDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
```

Answer (score 2):

Via [apple developers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html):

//1408709486 - time interval value

```
NSDate *lastUpdate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1408709486];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSLog(@"date time: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:lastUpdate]);
```

You will get:
date time: Aug 22, 2014, 3:11:26 PM

Answer (score 0):

[`NSTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/) to [`NSDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/) conversion in Swift:

```
let timeInterval = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() // this is the time interval
NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timeInterval)
```

Answer (score -1):

As Josh answer detailed the correct way, if you still want the interval to be in the NSDate format you can use the following method

```
+ (NSDate *) dateForHour:(int) hour andMinute: (int) minute{
     NSDateComponents * components = [NSDateComponents new];
     components.hour = hour;
    components.minute = minute;
    NSDate * retDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
return retDate;}
```