# NSTimeInterval Formatting

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimeinterval

I want to take my `NSTimeInterval` and format it into a string as 00:00:00 (hours, minutes, seconds). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The answer you accepted on [NSTimeInterval to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971807/nstimeinterval-to-nsdate) already shows you how to do this.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I understand it looks like James is shopping around but to be fair, I do consider the accepted answer here to be superior since it uses NSDateFormatter, which takes care of the all the pesky details that the other answer struggles with. I'm upvoting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
NSTimeInterval interval = ...;    
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];    
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"hh:mm:ss %@", formattedDate);
```

Comment: Could you explain the `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970`? How is 1/1/1970 relevant? I am not doubting that your code works (and I'm about to try it out), I'm just curious as to why. Thanks!

Comment: @James: 1/1/1970 is the [Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch); the beginning of time.

Comment: Just for future reference for those coming around and finding this, using the code provided was displaying the string as the date would be in my current time zone (00:00:00 - 05:00:00 [my time zone is -5] would display 19:00:00). To fix this, I changed the date to UTC by adding `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];`

Comment: Don't use dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:. Use dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: instead since the latter is the designated initializer and more accurate.

Comment: This will incorrectly display hour durations > 24 hours as `hours%24` - that is, a duration of 26 hours, 35 minutes will display as `02:35:00`

Answer (score 107):

Since iOS 8.0 there is now `NSDateComponentsFormatter` which has a `stringFromTimeInterval:` method.

```
[[NSDateComponentsFormatter new] stringFromTimeInterval:timeInterval];
```

Comment: For short time intervals it is worth noting that this method truncates seconds rather than rounding. So you should round the timeInterval first.

Answer (score 62):

"Best" is subjective.  The simplest way is this:

```
unsigned int seconds = (unsigned int)round(myTimeInterval);
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u:%02u",
    seconds / 3600, (seconds / 60) % 60, seconds % 60];
```

### UPDATE

As of iOS 8.0 and Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), you can use `NSDateComponentsFormatter` if you need a locale-compliant solution.  Example:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 1234.56;
NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute |
    NSCalendarUnitSecond;
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorPad;
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:interval];
NSLog(@"%@", string);
// output: 0:20:34
```

However, I don't see a way to force it to output two digits for the hour, so if that's important to you, you'll need to use a different solution.

Comment: This is great. But it would be more correct to replace the "NSUInteger" with "unsigned int", to match the "%02u" format specifier. "NSUInteger" is not an "unsigned int" on all hardware and all iOS versions. This fix will silence harmless errors.

Answer (score 4):

swift 4.2

```
extension Date {
    static func timestampString(timeInterval: TimeInterval) -> String? {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 0
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        return formatter.string(from: timeInterval)
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
let hour = 60 * 50 * 32
Date.timestampString(timeInterval: TimeInterval(hour))

// output "26:40:00"
```

Change `unitStyle` to get different styles. like `formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated` get

output: `"26h 40m 0s"`

Answer (score 0):

A Swift version of @Michael Frederick's answer :

```
let duration: NSTimeInterval = ...
let durationDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: duration)
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
let durationString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(durationDate)
```