# Format to MM:SS using NSDateComponentsFormatter

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, foundation, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I'm trying to format to `MM:SS` using `NSDateComponentsFormatter`:

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()

formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad
formatter.allowedUnits = .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond

let time: NSTimeInterval = 5
let timeText = formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(time)
```

The problem is, that even though I specified `.Pad`, the result is `0:05` instead of `00:05`.

Here's the relevant piece from Apple's documentation:

```
static var Pad: NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehavior { get } 
// Off: "1:0:10", On: "01:00:10"
```

I've tried to add `.CalendarUnitHour` just to try it and got `H:MM:SS` instead of `HH:MM:SS` despite what the documentation says.

How can I pad the very first number as shown in the documentation?

Comment: This is crazy, but I have the exact opposite result. Using swift playgrounds with a `DateComponentsFormatter` I get `00:05`. However, I want `0:05`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for wrong initial answer, there is no way to add leading zeros to hours:

> When days, hours, minutes, and seconds are allowed, the value is displayed as “0d 1:00:00” using the positional style, and as “0d 1h 0m 0s” using the abbreviated style.

If you simply need to format NSTimeInterval into string like HH:MM:SS check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128083/nstimeinterval-formatting/8128243#8128243)