# ios minutes to time

Tags: ios

I want to go from *minutes* as an `int` (eg 92) to a string of `1:32`. Is there a fancy way to do this using `objc` or I'm I stuck with figuring it out the *old-fashioned* way?

Comment: Not to be cynical, but a great start would be to read the documentation built into Xcode. It is a very good resource.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do not believe there is a function to do this, but it is simple enough to do on your own.

```
int hour = minutes / 60;
int min = minutes % 60;

NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat: %@"%d:%02d", hour, min];
```

The '02' will pad the results so there are always two digits in the minutes place. It may be useful to look at the [NSDate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as it may save you time if you want to do calculations on the result.

Comment: While you CAN use NSDate for this (see netrace's answer) this is a much faster way of doing it.

Comment: This way lacks localization support, so it is really basic

Answer (score 3):

I think you can find the answer here: [NSTimeInterval to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971807/nstimeinterval-to-nsdate)

The `int` you talking about should be `NSTimeInterval` (that is just `double`), convert it to a `NSDate` object and then format it using the `NSDateFormatter` with: `HH:mm`.

It can also could be more useful "extend" using categories NSDate object

```
@interface NSDate (Minutes)
```

and put there a method convert minutes to HH:mm (maybe could be better to move the format string as method parameter) so you never more need think about it.