# iOS: Formatting & localizing timers / time counters

Tags: ios, localization, nsdateformatter, nsnumber, foundation

In my project, I have used `NSDateFormatter` to properly format the dates displayed in my application. To be more specific, here is an example:

```
English: 12:34 am
Arabic: ١٢:٣٤ ص
```

Looks great, shows the numerals that I need. However, I have a time counter/timer that is counting up/down in the app:

```
01:31:22 // HH:mm:ss
```

How would I properly localize this counter to be displayed as:

```
٠١:٣١:٢٢
```

I checked `NSDateFormatter`, but it doesn't really represent this particular use case, as far as I can see. `NSNumberFormatter` seems to work for currencies and percentages.

---

**Why `NSDateFormatter` Doesn't Make Sense:**

Because it has `NSTimeZone` property, and has `am/pm` suffix which are both useless when we want to use counters.

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` should represent this particular use case, it's a representation of some form of date. How does it not work for you?

Comment: @WDUK I have a variable containing the number of seconds, and I should turn that into `HH:mm:ss`. In order to use `NSDateFormatter`, I have to convert the seconds that I have to a `NSDate`, but it doesn't make sense to me. (I hope I am making sense).

Comment: It makes sense, you want to format a date interval. Right, this isn't going to be that simple. Sounds like you **might** (can't confirm yet) need a custom formatter to achieve the effect you're after. I'll have a look in a few hours, but in the meantime see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/CreatingACustomFormatter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000196-CJBFABHB

Comment: There is this already in existence (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971807/nstimeinterval-to-nsdate), but this doesn't take into account locales.

Comment: @WDUK Thanks, this is definitely worth checking. I think I got a simple solution for the time being, which is to format each component on its own (HH, mm, ss). But I am not sure how to add the padding: 01 (%02d)

Comment: @WDUK Your second comment is what I currently have. I would like to localize it :)

Comment: I'm on it, will need a few hours though (unless someone answers in the meantime!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right then, I think I have something for you. I've created a basic `NSFormatter` subclass, which will do the trick for you. All you need to do, it provide it with an `NSNumber`, that contains an `NSTimeInterval`.

The .h and .m are available here: https://github.com/WDUK/WDCountdownFormatter

And here is some example code using it, and yes, it should respect locales.

```
WDCountdownFormatter* format = [[WDCountdownFormatter alloc] init];
NSLog(@"70 - %@",[format stringForObjectValue:@(70)]);
NSLog(@"179 - %@",[format stringForObjectValue:@(179)]);
NSLog(@"-10 - %@",[format stringForObjectValue:@(-10)]); // Invalid, will return nil
NSLog(@"0 - %@",[format stringForObjectValue:@(0)]);
NSLog(@"9827193 - %@",[format stringForObjectValue:@(9827193)]);
NSLog(@"1 - %@",[format stringForObjectValue:@(1)]);
```

Produces

```
// UK English
2012-11-28 23:11:11.453 StackOverflow[28687:c07] 70 - 00:01:10
2012-11-28 23:11:11.456 StackOverflow[28687:c07] 179 - 00:02:59
2012-11-28 23:11:11.457 StackOverflow[28687:c07] -10 - (null)
2012-11-28 23:11:11.458 StackOverflow[28687:c07] 0 - 00:00:00
2012-11-28 23:11:11.458 StackOverflow[28687:c07] 9827193 - 2729:46:33
2012-11-28 23:11:11.459 StackOverflow[28687:c07] 1 - 00:00:01

// Egyptian Arabic
2012-11-28 22:59:54.057 StackOverflow[28400:c07] 70 - ٠٠:٠١:١٠
2012-11-28 22:59:54.659 StackOverflow[28400:c07] 179 - ٠٠:٠٢:٥٩
2012-11-28 22:59:55.473 StackOverflow[28400:c07] -10 - (null)
2012-11-28 22:59:56.464 StackOverflow[28400:c07] 0 - ٠٠:٠٠:٠٠
2012-11-28 22:59:57.311 StackOverflow[28400:c07] 9827193 - ٢٧٢٩:٤٦:٣٣
2012-11-28 23:10:36.657 StackOverflow[28400:c07] 1 - ٠٠:٠٠:٠١
```

Comment: Wow, this is so neat. The best thing about it is that you haven't forgotten the padding.

Comment: No problem, keep an eye on the GitHub, I'll probably improve it in the future (no need to pass in an NSNumber, millisecond support, retain/release support [you need ARC for this at the moment], etc...). Glad to help :)

Comment: you can change formatter in WDCountDownFormatter like this to print number in arabic or persian locale: [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"per"]];