# Is this method going to always give me 12:00:00 of the current day in ios?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimeinterval

Yes, this is similar to [NSDate beginning of day and end of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324633/nsdate-beginning-of-day-and-end-of-day), but that topic does not discuss whether it works for all situations which is what I am asking here. That question dealt with not getting back the correct value because they forgot NSDayCalendarUnit. This question is dealing with the accuracy of the value which as it turns out is not going to work with DST as I had suspected.

In several parts of my app, I have the need to specify a time of day without caring about the actual day, e.g., do this activity at 4:00pm every day. I have seen a few posts that talk about how to do this, but would like feedback on my approach. The method below is intended to return midnight of any particular day and will be used in conjunction with an offset that represents the number of seconds to a particular time (for instance, 1:00:00 am as 3600).

I believe it should work, but am curious if it will handle edge cases such as daylight savings time. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
// We want to return 12:00:00AM of the day represented by the time interval
NSTimeInterval getStartOfDay(NSTimeInterval t)
{
   // first convert the time interval to an NSDate
   NSDate *ourStartingDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:t] ;

   // get just the year, month, and day of our date
   unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
   NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
   NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:ourStartingDate];
   NSDate *ourConvertedDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps] ;

   // put that date into a time interval
   NSTimeInterval convertedInterval = [ourConvertedDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] ;

   // because the time interval is in GMT and we may not be, we need to get an offset
   NSInteger timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone ] secondsFromGMT] ;

   // account for the time zone difference
   convertedInterval = convertedInterval - timeZoneOffset ;

   // still might have a Daylight Savings Time issue?
   return convertedInterval ;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDate beginning of day and end of day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324633/nsdate-beginning-of-day-and-end-of-day)

Comment: What do you mean, "the day represented by the time interval"? [`NSTimeInterval`s don't represent days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971807/nstimeinterval-to-nsdate/7972086#7972086), they represent _intervals_. You have to have a start point in order for the interval to give you an end point. What's your start point, and why don't you just begin with an `NSDate`?

Comment: Write a unit test for your method with date ranges covering the life cycle of the solar system, which is currently +/- 4.5e9 years?

Comment: @hd1 - thanks for the pointer to that topic

Comment: @JoshCaswell - the function is just a snippet. From where I use it, it is passing in a time interval that does represent a day to the user. I am using intervals as the back end is core data and it is easier to just use them directly. Plus, as you pointed out, it is just an interval which is what I ultimately want -- seconds since midnight.

Comment: @ott--yeah, I'll get right on that

Answer (score 2):

This will not handle edge cases.  In Brazil, DST either eliminates or duplicates the midnight-to-one-AM hour.  So on some days, there is **no** midnight, and on others there are **two** midnights.

The correct way to handle this is to either make your own data type representing a time of day (independent of date), or to use `NSDateComponents`, setting only the time-of-day components.

If you want to represent a date, independent of a time-of-day, you're better off using noon of that day than using midnight.  Or you can create your own data type, or use `NSDateComponents`, storing only day/month/year/era.

I **highly** recommend you watch these WWDC videos ASAP:

- [WWDC 2011 Session 117: Performing Calendar Calculations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=117)
- [WWDC 2013 Session 227: Solutions to Common Date and Time Challenges](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?id=227)