# How to get NSDate Object from hours and minutes only using NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, io

I have 55:33  as `NSString`  (55 hours and 33 minutes)
and I want to get `NSDate` object of it

Comment: What date do you want from a duration? It doesn't make much sense to convert a duration to a date unless it's relative to another date.

Comment: Related: [NsTimeInterval to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7971807)

Comment: I want to perform some math in 2 dates 
such as adding them