# How to convert sql timestamp to date in swift?

Tags: ios, sql, swift, datetime, timestamp

I get timestamp results from database SQL query like `1465536311` or `1465540078`. How to convert such number to current date and time in swift?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971807/nstimeinterval-to-nsdate

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 well, I don't know that was called `NSTimeInterval`. If it is, I also worried that the starting point to count the interval between SQL and iOS is different. So it wouldn't naturally occur to me to search for time interval conversion for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From  [NSDate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780353-init) :

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1465536311)
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer. Btw, I only can found the `timeIntervalSince1970` reference in NSDate class reference. Thanks!